# Check is record exists before inserting

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a php script to insert new parts into a postgres database. I want to check if the part exists before it is created. How can I do this. I am using the usual INSERT INTO clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `SELECT` first, to know if you must `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, like:

```
if (
    $db->fetchOne(
        'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM parts WHERE article_number = ?',
        $p->article_number
    )
) {
    $db->update(
        'parts',
        $p->to_array(),
        $db->quoteInto('article_number = ?', $p->article_number)
    );
}
else {
    $db->insert('parts', $p->to_array());
}
```

Re Milen's comment: great point! With the default PostgreSQL transaction isolation level (`READ COMMITTED`) it's possible that another process inserts (and commits) "your" part after your `SELECT`, but before your `INSERT`.

For the kind of apps we build, we normally just catch the DB exception, and do something about it (inform the user, retry). Or you can go with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`. See [Transaction Isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/transaction-iso.html).

Comment: Ok, do a SELECT else clause. I am a newbie at this, may you assist by showing me the code? I can do the SELECT but not the else bit. Many thanks for your great mind.

Comment: I've added the code Russel. $db is a Zend_Db_Adapter http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter

Comment: What happens when a record with the same article_number was inserted right after the  check for existence and before the inserting (a.k.a. race condition)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Milen. It's definitely something to be aware of. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into parts(article_number,category) 
select 'KEYB','COMPTR' 
where not exists(select * from parts where article_number = 'KEYB')
```

Comment: great solution, if we want to ignore duplicates silently. does not suffer race condition. I use it myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you rarely expect conflicts: Take the optimistic approach and just insert the new one and handle the uniqueness violation if it occurs. This will invalidate the current transaction when it fails, so if you're doing a lot of work in it, it'll be worthwhile to check first. In that case, I prefer `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ...)`.

Anyway, you *must* handle the possibility for a uniqueness violation. Even if you check first, there is a possibility that a concurrent transaction inserts the same record and commits first.